# Google ClientID works for Google Sign-in platform library but not new GIS library

Tags: vue.js, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm trying to migrate my application from the older Google Sign-In platform library to the newer Google Identity Services library.

I have a client ID that works for the old method, but when I load the "Google Sign-in" button using GIS, I get 403 errors and an error log that GSI_Logger says my origin is not allowed for the client ID. I'm on localhost, but when I use the old method, there are no issues with localhost.

The only thing I can think of being different is that I load my Google client ID as a constant and rendered the button in the `mounted()` section of my Vue app's `Login.vue`, while previously I loaded it in `main.js`.

Comment: set the JavaScript origin to https:\\localhost or show me the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Google One Tap can only be displayed in HTTPS domains".

So, it doesn't work because localhost is HTTP. I deployed to my testing environment which is HTTPS and got no such 403 errors.

Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid